# Angular speed and RPM of truck wheels

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

A truck with $48$ in. diameter wheels is traveling at $50$ mph

a) Find the angular speed of the wheels in rad/min

b) How many revolutions per minute does the wheel make?

So for (a), I know that one rotation of the wheel is $48\pi$ in.

I also know that in one hour the truck travels $50\quad mi.\quad \cdot \quad 5280\quad ft.\quad \cdot \quad 12\quad in.\quad =\quad 3168000\quad in.$

I do: $\frac { 3168000\quad in. }{ 60\quad min. } $ to find how how many inches it goes in one min. $52800 in./min.$

Now I am stuck. I don't know where to go from here to find the angular speed or RPM.
I would prefer a hint, rather than an answer, to get me back on track and get my mind on the right path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have computed the arc length traversed in one minute.

By definition, the radian measure, $\theta$, of a central angle subtended by an arc of length $s$ in a circle with radius $r$ is

$$\theta = \frac{s}{r}$$

The angular speed is

$$\omega = \frac{\theta}{t}$$

You can compute the radian measure of the angle through which the wheels turn in one minute since you know $s$ and can determine $r$ using the diameter.

To obtain the number of revolutions, divide the arc length by the circumference.

A note about conversions:  When you determine the number of inches the truck travels in one hour, you should write

$$50~\frac{\text{mi}}{\text{h}} \cdot 5280~\frac{\text{ft}}{\text{mi}} \cdot 12~\frac{\text{in}}{\text{ft}} = 3168000~\text{in}$$

to illustrate how the units are related.  Doing so can prevent you from making an error.

Comment: $v=r\omega$ $\omega =\frac { v }{ r } $ 
$\omega =\frac { 52800\quad in/min }{ 24\quad in } $
$=2200 rad/min$

yes?

Comment: You are correct.